# acessing azure databricks data from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-databricks

I am running the following command from a kubernetes cluster to access a file from azure databricks

```
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" --conf "spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.HDFSLogStore" script.py
```

I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2593)
```

Do I need to install any jars from hadoop azure. Please guide me

Comment: why not run it directly on Databricks?

Comment: We are doing a POC to access Spark directly from the kubernetes. The s3 file is part of a delta table